# How to crop image without forcing the user to select area

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image-processing, ecmascript-6

I need some cropping solution for creating 2 different images: 100x100px and 170x170px and the crop should happen in the middle of the image (for vertical and horizontal images) and the user shouldn't do anything, it should just happen automatically.

Is there some tool I could use for this? All the cropping tools I see require some input from the user.

Comment: You can crop an image by drawing it on a smaller canvas and grabbing the canvas's pixels as the new image.

Comment: @ChrisG I'm not very experienced with canvas, do you know of some tutorial that does something similar? And thank you for the idea!

Comment: Just look up how to draw an image to a canvas, then look up how to save a canvas as image. I don't know of a tutorial, no.